# BitBucket pass variable to a Pipe

Tags: dockerfile, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, docker-build

I'm trying to send a variable to a pipe which is sending the same variable to the docker build. We have that variable set in the deployments section and as far as I know the actual value would not be printed in the logs, which is causing that I still see the value as "$nexus_password".

```
   Build-With-Docker:
      - step:
          oidc: true
          script:
            - pipe: xxx/pipes-oidc-login-helper:1.0.0
            - pipe: xxx/pipes-docker-build-push:1.1.0-rc.0
              variables:
                BUILD_ARGS: ['--build-arg=\"nexus_username=$nexus_username\"', '--build-arg=\"nexus_password=$nexus_password\"']
```

Which is a pipe that it is receiving that values and using we are using this doc as guide to parse them in a bash script.

```
init_array_var() {
    local array_var=${1}
    local count_var=${array_var}_COUNT
    for (( i = 0; i < ${!count_var:=0}; i++ ))
    do
      eval ${array_var}[$i]='$'${array_var}_${i}
    done
}

init_array_var 'BUILD_ARGS'

echo "${BUILD_ARGS[@]}"

docker build "${BUILD_ARGS[@]}" -t ${ECR_REGISTRY}${IMAGE}:${IMAGE_TAG} .
```

`https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/advanced-techniques-for-writing-pipes/` 
in the pipeline logs it seems to be printing the --build-arg correctly.

`Building image... --build-arg="nexus_username=$nexus_username" --build-arg="$nexus_password"`

and this is what we have in our Dockerfile

`RUN TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true mvn -Drepo.username=${nexus_username} -Drepo.pwd=${nexus_password} -s deployment/settings.xml clean package`  
I'm 100% sure that it is something to do with all of the parsing that we do along the way but the credentials work 100% if we put them directly into the RUN command.